# Do I need to keep any cautions in mind when transfering an external SSD into my Macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, external-disk

Hi I am now successfully running my MacbookPro off of a bootable external SSD (which is runnung Yosemite and onto which I cloned my whole system) and I would like to switch it out with the old HDD inside my laptop (just have to wait a few days until I can borrow the screwdrivers).

I *assume* I can just follow the normal steps of replacing a hard drive since everything is operating off the SSD at the moment and the HHD is prettymuch dormant, but I am not well versed in this area so I just want to check before I go doing it.

So, do I need to do anything special in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing that I can think of.

My own experience was just - clone, test for a few days, decide all was good.
Then, eventually retire the old drive for good.

You might want to check that the new drive has the correct Recovery Partition in place before making the final swap.

Disk Utility can tell you if the partition is present, if you set the Debug menu to 'show every partition', but I'm not sure how to tell whether it's the Yosemite recovery partition.

Booting into it with no other drive connected would be the certain way; assuming no-one else comes up with a nifty way to ask Terminal etc.

Comment: Thanks for the amswer. When I first connected the SSD to my computer I partitioned it (like all the youtube videos said to do), though Im not totally sure what that did. Then I cloned using Carbon Copy Cloner. I read somewhere that CCC automatically does a Recovery Partition for you. Do you know if thats true?

Comment: Partitioning a non-boot drive won't necessarily add the requisite Recovery Partition, so it's wise to check. Once you're happy with that & that the drive is behaving well under daily use, the old drive can go bye-byes, or drop it in a drawer as a last-resort disaster recovery, if ever needed. *edit* not sure about CCC, I think it does. The quick boot test will make sure, I'd think.